# Generar tabla especial en javascript

Tags: javascript

Mi pregunta es:

**¿Cómo hacer una tabla en javascript en donde salgan los números de la tabla del 5 intercalados en dos columnas, y las otras dos queden en blanco?**

Este es el código:

```
function tabla() {
    document.write("<table border='3' bgcolor='aqua'>");
    var num = 0,
    var resultado = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {   
        for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {   
            if ((i % 2) == 0) {
                document.write("<td>");
                document.write(num += 5);
                document.write("</td>");

            } else {

                document.write("<td>");
                document.write("---");
                document.write("</td>");
            }
        }   
    }   
    document.write("</table>"); 
}
```

Y este es el resultado que espero obtener:

[image: Resultado gráfico]

Comment: Hola @Trujillo acabo de editar la respuesta para cumplir con el formato de tabla que dices, revisala a ver si te sirve.

Comment: hola @JuanPinzón agradezco mucho su colaboración, Es ud muy amable.

Answer (score 2):

Para lograr hacer la tabla que mencionas podrías hacer algo así:

```js
function tabla(){
  var t = "<table border='3' bgcolor='aqua'>";
  var num=1, resultado=0;
  
  for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
    t += "<tr>";
    for (var j=0; j<5; j++){
      if ((j%2)=== 0) {
        t += "<td>";
        resultado = num * 5;
        t += resultado;
        t += "</td>";
        num++;
      }else{
        t += "<td>";
        t += "---";
        t += "</td>";
      }
    }
    t += "</tr>";
  }
  t += "</table>";
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= t;
}
tabla();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="demo">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```